# Facebook Graph API Photos Random

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I have recently been fiddling with the FB Graph API. Im wondering if what I would like to do is possible. I want the last 11 photos uploaded to the album to be pulled from facebook. I have manged to get the photos populating fine but not sure if its pulling the last uploaded?

Also, if this isn't possible, is it possible to pull 11 random photos from the album? Could you pull them all in and somehow choose a random selection in the forloop to display the images?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{$album_id}/photos?fields=photos.order(chronological),picture,images&limit=11&access_token={$access_token}"
```

Thanks
Joe

Comment: "not sure if its pulling the last uploaded" - why not just...check on facebook.com if they are the last ones? there is no way to pull random photos btw. you would need to get ALL photos and pick them on your own.

Comment: `photos.order(chronological)` where did you get this syntax from? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/album/photos does not document any such `order` parameter. Not even `photos?fields=photos` makes much sense. And since in Graph API Explorer I can replace that part with `fields=photos.order(foo)` or even `fields=phutuz.order(foo)` without getting any error message ... I doubt this has any effect at all.